# Software compatible with Windows 7 and a Netgear n600 router for logs?

Tags: windows, networking

I am running on Windows 7 with a Netgear N600 router and I'm looking for free software to view detailed event logs. Specifically who is connected to my network and when, but more importantly what URL'S they are visiting. Remote access is a plus. Emails would be great. My N600 router comes with the "Genie" software with an opendns feature but I haven't received an email to date, and the open dns page it automatically takes me to gives me no options or information. Please be specific. I just want to set it and view the urls when I can. Monitor what is happening on my network.

I can't find any information that is straight forward. Any recommendations are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

If you really need to take a detailed look at what is going on on your network then either [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) or [scapy](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/) would allow you to actively monitor what is going on on the network.  Wireshark records every packet while scapy can be programmed in python to do just about anything.  Both are cross platform and work by examining the network traffic rather than by querying the router.